# Base64Encoded JSON data as param in URLRequest in swift 5

Tags: json, swift, base64, urlsession

I need to make an API request in a swift app I am working on and the requirements are, it needs to be json encoded and then base 64 encoded.

I thought I had it figured out, but I am getting an error in Xcode saying

> Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Data?'

Here is a simplified version of what I am doing...

```
let params: [String: Any] = ["connection_id": 123456]
var request = URLRequest(url: url!) //url is stored as a variable in my class
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = Data(jsonData!).base64EncodedString() //<--This is where the error is
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
//send out the request with URLSession.shared.dataTask
```

How can I have a base64encoded string of the json object as the param in the request if Xcode tells me the type must be Data?

Answer (score 0):

`base64EncodedString` returns a string when httpBody is expecting `Data`. You just need to use `base64EncodedData` instead.

Also, note, oh boy is this code dangerous. So much forced unwrapping (using exclamation points). I recommend learning how to avoid using force unwrapping in the vast majority of places.

**Edit**: Since it returns optional Data, you will need to unwrap it. A slight improvement over forced unwrapping would be to provide a default value as an empty body:

```
request.httpBody = jsonData?.base64EncodedData() ?? Data()
```

Comment: It seems like using base64EncodedData is giving me"Optional(44 bytes)" instead of the actual data.

Comment: @NeglectedSanity That is because it is optional Data, I updated my answer to show you how to handle that

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. The error goes away, but now my server is showing an empty array as the POST. Using my initial question and updating with your answer I can send the request but on the server I have a simple "print_r($_POST, true);" and it is showing an empty array, like the app isn't actually sending anything.